# passport middleware does not run

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, ejs

I am using passportJS for authentication. I have called a function setAuthenticatedUser in app.js

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
app.use(passport.setAuthenticatedUser);
```

This is my middleware in a file ./config/passport-local.js

```
passport.setAuthenticatedUser = async function (req, res, next) {
    if (await req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // req.user contains the current signed in user from the session cookie and we are just sending this to the locals for the views
        res.locals.user = req.user;
        // console.log('Locals\' user loaded');
    }
    next();
}
```

There isn't a error but setAuthenticatedUser doesn't run after calling in app.js. Instead I have to manually call the middleware from each routes

```
router.get('/', passport.setAuthenticatedUser, homeController.home);
router.get('/route1', passport.setAuthenticatedUser,homeController.route1);
router.get('/route2', passport.setAuthenticatedUser, homeController.route2);
router.get('/route3', passport.setAuthenticatedUser, homeController.route3);
router.get('/route4', passport.setAuthenticatedUser, homeController.route4);
```

I will be adding a lot more routes in future. What do I do so that I don't have to add the middleware for each get req?

Let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flipping the order of the last two calls to `app.use`. Express will call those functions in order as defined.

I'm assuming your routes defined in `./routes` don't call `next()`, so there's no way for the next set of middlewares (in this case `passport.setAuthenticatedUser`) to run. So make sure that this call to the Passport function happens before your route handler, or more generally, before any function that won't call `next()`.